# Knowing Owner of given IP address is possible or not?

Tags: ip-address

Recently my google account has been hacked, after recovery of my account i found one IP address of that hacker. I want to know his/her details i.e., name, location etc..

Is it possible to do that? If so please tell...

Thanks In advance..

Comment: is this for revenge or...?

Comment: just to  know who the guy was

Comment: just so you know, IP addresses can be dynamic. They contain generic information like ISP and region but they don't contain information on the user specifically since the same address can be used by different people at different times. Anyway having your google account stolen means nothing it's not like you're going to be able to do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

> Knowing Owner of given IP address is possible or not?

No, you can't do it by your serlf, but the cop can do that.